# Having trouble deleting custom annotation in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

I am trying to delete a custom annotation placed on a map. The problem is, in order to delete that annotation the user has to press the delete button I made, twice. This is the line of code that deletes the annotation, `[mv removeAnnotation:[mv.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0]]`. I am almost positive that by default my current location (MKUserLocation) is always the first annotation in the array and this is why I have to press delete twice. Am I on the right track? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
NSLog(@"\n\n\n################################\nANNOATION SELECTED\n################################");



_currentAnnotation = view.annotation;
[self zoomOnAnnotation:_currentAnnotation];

 NSLog(@"selectedannotationview is %@", _currentAnnotation);

[viewLoadingCover setHidden:FALSE];
[actIndLoading startAnimating];
//Annotation *currentAnnotation = view.annotation;
currentAnnoView = view;
//if (isLoadingCallout) {
    [self getCurrentMapDataWithLatitute:_currentAnnotation.coordinate.latitude Longitute:_currentAnnotation.coordinate.longitude];
//}


if ([view.annotation isEqual:mapView.userLocation])
{
    isUser = YES;
    //NSLog(@"##### yes this is user location annotation");
    if (!view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {
        //NSLog(@"##### yes view.rightCalloutAccessoryView is NIL");
        mapView.userLocation.title = @"Loading...";
        mapView.userLocation.subtitle = @" ";
        //NSLog(@"##### cityAndState(subtitle) = %@", cityAndState);
        //[[mapView userLocation] setSubtitle:[NSString stringWithString:cityAndState]];
        userButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = userButton;
        [userButton addTarget:self action:@selector(UIButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        NSLog(@"userlocation selected---------------------------%@", cityAndState);
    }

    reverseG= [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
    reverseG.delegate = self;
    [reverseG start];
}
else
{
    isUser = NO;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest NSLogging mv.selectedAnnotations count to see what's happening there. Wouldn't deleting annotation at index 1 instead of 0 whenever the count's >1 quickly prove your theory right or wrong?

Comment: Yes Samuli you're right. When I attempt to use index 1 it crashed because it is out of bounds. When I output the array `NSLog(@"Array for annot = %@",self.annotations);` I get over 300 lines of annotations when in reality there is only about 4 that have been plotted on the map. Maybe it updates the annotation as it zooms in. This does sound feasible as the annotations latitude and longitude will change until the desired zoom level is reached.

-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Answer (score 0):

Would you be interested in the delegate methods MKMapView

```
- (Void) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView didSelectAnnotationView: (MKAnnotationView *) view;
- (Void) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView didDeselectAnnotationView: (MKAnnotationView *) view;
```

Through them you will know what annotation selected or deselected.

Comment: Thanks Aliaksandr, I have posted my didSelectedAnnotationView. I thought I had it nailed because I sent the selectedAnnotation to be removed but for some odd reason it still takes 2 attempts.